# Legion y530 (GTX 1050 M) two external monitor. Usb-c or Mini DisplayPort?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, lenovo, hdmi

I want to buy second external monitor which is going to be connected to my Lenovo Legion y530 laptop. Right now I have one external monitor 2k connected via HDMI port. Laptop has also miniDP and USB-C.

Which way is better to connected second 2k monitor? I heard that nVidia GTX 1050M use only HDMI and miniDP. It is truth?

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu? It is a hardware shopping question.

Comment: Does Lenovo claim anywhere that Thunderbolt or Displayport on USB-C are supported for video?

Comment: @Pilot6 Well, assuming one is running Ubuntu on it, the question would presumably be about whether Ubuntu works with USB-C video methods, assuming the hardware supports it.

Comment: @dobey exactly. I know that on Windows 10 it works with 3 external monitors connected by USB-c, HDMI and miniDP. The question is: it is works on Ubuntu too?

Comment: @dzierzak You need to answer the question I asked above. If the USB-C monitor is DisplayLink, it likely won't work by default, as that is a proprietary solution. Thunderbolt should be supported though. In any case, you can just boot a live image off USB to test for yourself.